# Proper event to populate a ComboBox/DropDownList inside of a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, combobox, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to figure out what the correct event would be to populate a ComboBox in a Telerik RadGrid or any ASP.NET grid from the CodeBehind. When the user clicks Edit on a row the ComboBox should be populated with its items.

The only examples I have seen are using the DataSourceID property in the aspx page. I prefer doing all of my populating manually in the code behind:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = colorList;  
Combobox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you need to bound the combobox and save the selected item somewhere? Is it in a template column or do you use the dropdown column? Are you working with a template form or auto generated form?

Answer (score 0):

You can access child controls in a grid column in:

- ItemDataBound - fired for each item (so you need to check for GridDataItem types or GridEditItem, depending on your goal)
- ItemCreated - similar, but you don't have the data item object associated with each item
- ItemCommand - when Edit is clicked an Edit command is invoked so you can access it.